# Unable to run .NET 3.5 unit test projects because of VS2012?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

***Question Background:***

I currently have two projects. Both have been built in Visual Studio 2012. Both projects have a Unit Test project in their respective solutions. One targets the .NET 4 framework, the other targets .NET 3.5.

***The Issue:***

Both of these projects run their tests fine **in VS**. When I try and run the .NET 3.5 project against MSTest.exe from the command line through a batch file I get the following message:

```
To be able to target your project to .NET Framework 3.5, you must use the steps
documented at the following Microsoft Web site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/
?LinkId=201405
```

The link information just suggests re-targeting the project to .NET 3.5 but as the project already targets .NET 3.5 I don't see how this will help!

I can run my other .NET 4 targeted project through the batch file with no issues.

**The real questions I have are:**

**1. As I have built my projects in VS2012, will it only run unit tests set to target the .NET 4 framework and up?**

**2. If I were to - for arguments sake - run this from VS2008, would it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4.0+ framework is installed with VS 2012. If you want to use .net 3.5 and low you should download and install it.

Comment: So as standard, even if I aimed the project at .NET 3.5 it will run it against .NET 4 as it was built in VS2012?

Comment: If you install VS 2012 only with 4.x framework, the global assembly Cache(GAC) is placed in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL.
When you build the project using .NET 4.0, the path for all shared assemblies is set to this GAC. So if you use .NET 4.5.1 for .NET 4.0 projects, it will work well, as the path to GAC is the same and the app will have the access to them everywhere with .NET 4.+.
But .NEt 3.5 GAC is placed in C:\Windows\assembly\
When you build the project created with .Net 3.5, the compiler changes the path to GAC of .NET 4.+ and this app will run only on PC with .NET 4.+